# Video doesn't play on Android 5.1

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I've got the following code:

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://packagename/"+R.raw.splash2;

Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

videoView.start();
```

It's not working on [Oppo A37F](https://www.gsmarena.com/oppo_a37-8162.php) although it worked on other devices. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
VideoView videoView;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.ViewVideo);


        String videopath = "android.resource://com.example.cloudanalogy.play_video/"+R.raw.a; //com.example.cloudanalogy.play_video this is my package name,and inside the raw file a.mp4 video
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(videopath);
        videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        videoView.start();
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code block

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash2;
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
videoView.start();
```